# Application form with phpMyAdmin database

Tags: php, html

So now I'm trying to make a application form for a trial drive lesson. I'm new at PHP, so I tried to take some code from my registration form that is working fully.

But nothing happens when i click submit(aanvraag_btn)

Here is the code:

```
<form class ="myform" action="index.php" method="post" >
    <h3 class="center"> Vraag een proefrit aan! </h3>

    <br></br>
    <input name="naam" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Naam" required /> 
    <br></br>
    <input name="email" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Email"/> 
    <br></br>

    <input name="Telefoonnummer" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" required /> 
    <br></br>

    <input name="aanvraag" type="button" id="aanvraag_btn" value="Aanvragen"           required/> <br>
```

This is the PHP:

```
   <?php

    if(isset($_POST['aanvraag']))
    {
            $naam = $_POST['naam'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $telefoonnummer = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];

            $query= "insert into user values('$naam','$email','telefoonnummer')";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            if($query_run)
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert ("Bedankt voor de aanvraag, we nemen zo snel mogelijk contact op.") </script>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert ("Error>';
            }
        }
```

?>

Comment: where is your database connections ?

Comment: Use type="submit" on your submit button.

Comment: My database connection is on top. <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Unable to connect");
 mysqli_select_db($con, 'form');
 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use type="submit"

```
<input name="aanvraag" type="submit" id="aanvraag_btn" value="Aanvragen"           required/>
```

Comment: Now it worked abit, but i get this error after i press the button : Notice: Undefined index: telefoonnummer in C:\xampp\htdocs\Easy drive\index.php on line 124

Comment: typo use caps T to get the post value because in form  element name is   Telefoonnummer  so its called like this $telefoonnummer = $_POST['Telefoonnummer'];

Comment: Ye that was exactly the problem - Jyothy. But im not getting any details in my database now.

Comment: <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Unable to connect");
 mysqli_select_db($con, 'form');
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
    <form class ="myform" action="index.php" method="post" >
        <h3 class="center"> Vraag een proefrit aan! </h3>



        <br></br>
        <input name="naam" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Naam" required /> 
        <br></br>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Email"/> 
        <br></br>

        <input name="Telefoonnummer" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" required /> 
        <br></br>

        <input name="aanvraag" type="submit" id="aanvraag_btn" value="Aanvragen"/> <br>

</form>
```

Comment: Its working now without error, but not getting any details in my database.

Answer (score 0):

1)Missing form close

2)missing type ="submit"

3)typo in element attribute near name="telefoonnummer"

```
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['aanvraag']))
        {
                $naam = $_POST['naam'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $telefoonnummer = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];

                $query= "insert into user values('$naam','$email','telefoonnummer')";
                $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

                if($query_run)
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert ("Bedankt voor de aanvraag, we nemen zo snel mogelijk contact op.") </script>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert ("Error");</script>';
                }

            }

    ?>

     <form class ="myform" action="index.php" method="post" >
            <h3 class="center"> Vraag een proefrit aan! </h3>



            <br></br>
            <input name="naam" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Naam" required /> 
            <br></br>
            <input name="email" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Email"/> 
            <br></br>

            <input name="Telefoonnummer" type="text" class="inputvalues" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" required /> 
            <br></br>

            <input name="aanvraag" type="submit" id="aanvraag_btn" value="Aanvragen"/> <br>

    </form>
```

Comment: the form close is there. aye i changed the attributes. Changed submit too, only problem now is im not getting any popup that the form has been submitted and also no information in database